# Vectorisation of code for insertion of 2x2 matrix along the diagonal of a large matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vectorization

I am trying to do an elementwise insertion of a small matrix (2x2) along the diagonal of a large matrix (10x10 say). Overlapping values are added, and the small matrix is only inserted where it can fit fully inside the large matrix.

I have achieved this using a for loop, but am curious whether the process can be vectorised.

```
function M = TestDiagonal()

N     = 10;
miniM = [1, -1; -1, 1];
M     = zeros(N);

for i = 1:N-1
    M(i:i+1,i:i+1) = M(i:i+1,i:i+1) + miniM;
end

end
```

Giving the desired matrix

```
 1    -1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
-1     2    -1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0    -1     2    -1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0    -1     2    -1     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0    -1     2    -1     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0    -1     2    -1     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0    -1     2    -1     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0    -1     2    -1     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0    -1     2    -1
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    -1     1
```

In the general case, the input will always be square, but can take any size. The step dimension will always be equal to 1.

Comment: Will the input always be 2×2? Can it be larger, or non-square (`m`×`n`)? In that case, what would the desired step be? Always 1 in each dimension? Or `m-1` and `n-1`?

Comment: The input will always be square, but can take any size. The step dimension will always be equal to 1.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. You can use the last part of my answer then, with `step = [1 1]` and `R = N-size(miniM,1)+1`. Next time please try to specify everything from the beginning, in the question text, and avoid using an example that doesn't reflect the general case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use 2D convolution (see [`conv2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html)).

## 2×2 case, step 1 along each dimension

```
M = conv2(eye(N-1), miniM);
```

## `m`×`m` case, step 1 along each dimension

```
M = conv2(eye(N-size(miniM-1)+1), miniM);
```

## `m`×`n` case, arbitrary steps along each dimension

In this case the steps need to be defined:

```
step = [2 1]; % desired step along each dimension
```

and it makes more sense to define a desired number of repetitions `R`, rather than the final size (`N`), because the latter may not be achievable with full repetitions of `miniM`:

```
R = 4; % desired number of repetitions
```

Then:

```
M = conv2(full(sparse(1:step(1):step(1)*R, 1:step(2):step(2)*R, 1)), miniM);
```

Example:

```
>> miniM = [10 20 30; 40 50 60];
>> R = 4;
>> step = [1 2];
>> M = conv2(full(sparse(1:step(1):step(1)*R, 1:step(2):step(2)*R, 1)), miniM)
M =
    10    20    30     0     0     0     0     0     0
    40    50    70    20    30     0     0     0     0
     0     0    40    50    70    20    30     0     0
     0     0     0     0    40    50    70    20    30
     0     0     0     0     0     0    40    50    60
```

Comment: @HansHirse I've tried to generalize. In the general case `N` may not be achievable, so I fix number of repetitions `R` instead

Comment: this is a very succinct solution, thank you. Is there a similarly succinct method for variable `miniM`? For example, if `miniM` was replaced by `deepMiniM   = randi(4,2,2,9);`  I'm not too familiar with stackOverflow, so I'm not sure if this justifies a separate question thread.

Comment: @JasonTracey Do you mean using a 3D array instead of 2D as input? Yes, that's different enough to deserve a new question, I _think_  — I'm not sure what the desired output would be in that case

Comment: Yes, using a 3D array as the input, but resulting in a 2D output as before. Using my initial example, this would be achieved by replacing the code inside the for loop with : `M(i:i+1,i:i+1) = M(i:i+1,i:i+1) + deepMiniM(:,:,i);` and by using the `deepMiniM` as defined earlier. I will submit this as a new question as long as this is not trivial.